# Pod scheduling in Openshift/Kubernetes

Tags: cron, openshift, schedule, kubernetes-pod

I would like to apply a daily schedule to a pod so that it is created at 9 AM and destroyed at 9 PM.

I believe this is possible using two almost-identical CronJobs set with the appropriate schedules.

The Jobs create a pod that runs the following commands in the morning and evening respectively:

```
...
command: ["oc scale dc my-dc",  "--replicas=1"] # The command to execute in the pod
...
```

```
...
command: ["oc scale dc my-dc",  "--replicas=0"] # The command to execute in the pod
...
```

To execute these commands I'm planning to use this image since it comes with the Openshift CLI installed: https://hub.docker.com/r/ebits/openshift-client

Can anyone advise any recommendations to carry out this task?
Are there any aspects I didn't consider?

Thanks

Comment: i think the answer to your problem can be found here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html
this describes how to create a cronjob resource running in your cluster

Comment: Thanks but I already know how to write a CronJob. I know I have to run an `oc` command in a container and I was looking for advice on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll share the method that worked for me.

The CronJob I wrote creates a container based on [this](https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-cli) image (remember to specify the Openshift version using the right tag) and runs the typical `oc` commands to login and scale the DC mentioned above.

The tricky part for me was to understand the correct syntax execute the commands in the container after creation.

Anyway, below I included the container definition I specified in the CronJob yaml file:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: oc-cli
      image: 'registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-cli:v3.11.153' # <===== SPECIFY YOUR OPENSHIFT VERSION
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          oc login https://<LOGIN URL>/
          --insecure-skip-tls-verify -u <LOGIN USERNAME> -p <LOGIN PASSWORD> ; oc scale
          dc/example --replicas=1 -n cronjob-test ;
...
```

Writing the password explicitly might be a problem so I added a Secret and made a reference to it in the same CronJob so that the secret data were part of the environment variables:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: oc-cli
      image: 'registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-cli:v3.11.153' # <===== SPECIFY YOUR OPENSHIFT VERSION
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          oc login $OC_URL --insecure-skip-tls-verify -u $OC_USER -p
          $OC_PASSWORD ; oc scale dc/example --replicas=5 -n
          cronjob-test ;
      env:
        - name: OC_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: oc-login-credentials
              key: username
        - name: OC_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: oc-login-credentials
              key: password
        - name: OC_URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: oc-login-credentials
              key: url
...
```

Unfortunately, [Red Hat](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html)'s documentation on the matter is not very helpful as it only provides one example.

[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)' docs were slightly more useful instead.